# VS2010: Problem with a test's Setup Script in VS2010 Test Settings

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest

In the VS2010 Test Settings file, I've specified a .bat file that invokes a powershell script.  Running the .bat file from a command prompt works just fine and the .bat returns in less than 5 secs.  However, if I try to run a test, the run eventually reports a 'not executed' result and reports an error "The setup batch file on agent machine [machinename] exceeded the execution timeout period" (which is 100s by default).  I am running the test locally (no seperate controller) using VS2010 Ultimate.

Has anyone run into this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the problem of test execution failing with exceeded timeout problem when the setup script contains call to powershell.exe. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796423/powershell-2-0-hang-when-run-from-msdeploy-pre-post-ops-using-c), the problem is that the powershell.exe does not exit until its input stream is open.

However I was able to make it working with the workaround mentioned [here](http://epeleg.blogspot.com/2010/06/solution-to-powershell-never-exists.html) (The workaround is to use null stream as input for the powershell.exe.)

powershell.exe dir **< NUL**

Regards
Aseem Bansal

Answer (score 0):

You can just write into your batch file:

powershell.exe < NUL -executionpolicy unrestricted -file "yourfilename"

That should also work.